# Does a heap binary tree have to complete in order to be a heap?

Tags: c++, heap

I have a little bit of confusion around heaps in c++, and I want to understand it better.

Must a binary tree be complete (full binary tree) in order to be classified as a heap?

Must a heap be a complete binary tree? Professor answer is no but I have not checked with the professor.

Online resources state heaps definition is that they must be complete binary trees. My professor states that a heap is a binary tree with two special properties.

Comment: Please point out the relevance of `C++` to this question. Are there specific definitions of `heap`, `complete binary tree` and `full binary tree` to refer to? (The statement from your professor sounds like part/a description of one.)

Comment: A heap must be a *complete* binary tree. It doesn't have to be a *full* binary tree. See http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~sheard/course/Cs163/Doc/FullvsComplete.html

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap, which explains those two special properties: the heap property and the shape property.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are specifically concerned of a binary heap.

On top of the key-ordering property, lowest level of a binary tree must be left-aligned and all levels above must be full in order to be classified as a binary heap. The lowest level does not have to be full. Such binary tree is typically denoted as **complete**, and if the lowest level is full it is denoted as **perfect**.

But if you are concerned about C++ implementation I guess that exact terminology is not what you are after -- binary heaps are nice for easy implementation using arrays and that will work alright for complete binary trees, not just perfect ones.